# Inserting date dd-mm-yyyy from maskedTextBox into db

Tags: sql, database, date, datetime, sql-insert

I'm getting an error while trying to insert a date into database, here is the insert command:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customer([date1])VALUES(Convert.ToDateTime(date1.Text))
```

the error is :

```
String was not recognized as a valid datetime.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a string.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(date1.Text)
```

will never compile to what you need. It will be send as such in the DB. Use a parameterized command and pass the result of this in a parameter.

For instance:

```
string sqlstring = "INSERT INTO Customer([date1])VALUES(@Date)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, conn);
SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter("@Date", Convert.ToDateTime(date1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```